# jQuery FormBuilder: Is there any way to prevent the field menu from transitioning into icons when the screen collapses less than 482 pixels?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm adding a form builder to my app using [jQuery formBuilder](https://formbuilder.readthedocs.io/en/latest/).   I'm wondering if there is a way to prevent the field names from collapsing after the window is resized to a smaller view (it seems like this occurs less than 482px.  You can see this on the working example on the formBuilder site).  I would prefer to see the resulting form collapse rather than the form fields, so that the user can always read the field names (i.i rather than seeing an icon).  I'm not versed in CSS, but it appears that there may be some phone/tablet optimizing going on that I'm not sure how to triage.  Any assistance/suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Welcome to SO. You need to at least try to accomplish the goal yourself and then share your progress / code. see [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: I've inspected in the browser, and changed styles to both the field div and the form div, but I'm going about it blindly as I little experience with front-end style formatting, etc.  You can see the formBuilder on the website, and can see that it collapses < 482.  Why?  I don't know. How to change the behavior? That's my question.